# Angular application throws exception at compile time

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, knex.js

I have an Angular 2 application, running in Electron and using Knex for database interaction that has successfully compiled and run several times over.  After several edits, I attempted to run the application locally and received the error `ReferenceError: "yexecutor is not defined"`.

Googling the error yielded no results.  I have gradually commented out every line of custom code written by me and still the error occurs.  I've even rebooted my rig thinking, perhaps, Node was just acting up.  After a reboot, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commenting all of my own code, rebooting and finally dying and coming back to life to try again, I remembered I was investigating the source of some of the packages I had installed.  So, I decided to try deleting the `node_modules` directory and execute an `npm install`.

A few minutes later, I'm back to a successful compile!

Steps to solve:

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. `npm install`

I must have fat fingered the keyboard while meandering through the packages! That, or my cats decided to become contributors.

Viola!

Comment: @msanford Copy that.